# Run function when previous has been finished

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I have two functions below and I need to execute them in a sequence, only when the first one finishes the next runs. But, this is not happening outputting just the second function.

In raw Lua, we can use `CALLBACK_MANAGER:FireCallbacks` and `CALLBACK_MANAGER:RegisterCallback` to handle this. How could I proceed with esp8266?

```
-- test.lua

function increase()
    a = 0
  tmr.alarm(1,1000,1,function()
    if (a == 10) then
      tmr.stop(1)
    else
      a = a + 1
    end
    print(a)
  end)
end

function decrease()
    a = 10
  tmr.alarm(1,1000,1,function()
    if (a == 0) then
      tmr.stop(1)
    else
      a = a - 1
    end
    print(a)
  end)
end

function start()
    increase()
    decrease()
end

start()
```

OUTPUT

```
➜ test git:(master) ✗ nu exec test.lua
➜ test git:(master) ✗ nu terminal
-- output
--- Miniterm on /dev/cu.wchusbserial1410  115200,8,N,1 ---
--- Quit: Ctrl+] | Menu: Ctrl+T | Help: Ctrl+T followed by Ctrl+H ---
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should call `decrease()` from inside `increase()` when all the increasing job is done.

Comment: Is this a good approach? What if a some time I need to execute only `increase()` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
-- test.lua

function increase()
    a = 0
    tmr.register(1,1000,tmr.ALARM_SEMI,function()
       if (a == 10) then
         tmr.unregister(1)
         if tmr.state(2) ~= nil then
            tmr.start(2) -- starts second timer if registered
         end
       else
         a = a + 1
       end
       print(a)
    end)
    tmr.start(1) -- starts first timer
end

function decrease()
    b = 10
    tmr.alarm(2,1000,tmr.ALARM_SEMI,function()
       if (b == 0) then
         tmr.unregister(2)
       else
         b = b - 1
       end
       print(a)
    end)
end

function start()
    increase() -- register and start first timer
    decrease() -- register second timer
end

start()
```

Possible solutions:

- Calling `decrease` from inside of function called by first timer.
- Making it a little bit cleaner and passing callback to `increase` using function parameter (and then doing same thing as in first point)(if something happens to passed function parameter you may want to move it to global scope as some kind of temporary variable; it is due to the nature of nodemcu itself).
- Registering `decrease` timer as second timer and starting it from `increase`'s callback.
- Splitting it into registering, starting and callbacks: first registering two timers with two different callbacks (one for decreasing, other one for increasing), then starting first one and from inside it's callback, when full cycle is finished - starting second timer and unregistering first one (basically previous point but a little bit extended).
- Creating third timer that waits for first timer to complete in order to start second one.
- Possibly other solutions like suspending `decrease` timer and resuming it later.

You should also consider not using magic numbers and go with e.g. `tmr.ALARM_SEMI`. There is also OOP-like model for timers, so if you feel more like using it then it is way easier to do.
More about it can be found [on tmr's docs](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/tmr/).

Comment: @hugalves Any particular errors? Or clean run of just increasing loop? Anyway problem is probably because `callback` is local to function and node has tendency to remove all local variables between calls (see second comment on second point). I will change answer to use two separate timers but this method is still valid if you move callback to global scope (or at least should be).